# Centrar formulario con Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo aquí un formulario, estoy intentando centrar los `input` y todo en general. No estoy consiguiendo resultado debido a que aún soy novato en la herramienta. ¿Cómo debería hacer para centrar el contenido?

Éste es mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Registro Usuario con BootStrap + NodeJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- NodeJS sirve para usar JavaScript en el servidor -->
</head>

<style>
  img {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <form class="form-horizontal">

  </form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/M/MSN_Messenger-logo-000410C523-seeklogo.com.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>Registro</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md">
          <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Nombre</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Encontre una respuesta a mi pregunta, la clave estaba en añadir `col-md-offset` y fiiiiin. A continuacion dejo la soolucion:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registro Usuario con BootStrap + NodeJS</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

     <!-- NodeJS sirve para usar JavaScript en el servidor -->
</head>

<style>
    img{
        max-width: 300px;
        max-height: 300px;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal">

    </form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/M/MSN_Messenger-logo-000410C523-seeklogo.com.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h1>Registro</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
            </div>

        </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes solucionar tu problema usando `Flexbox`:
Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como posicionar varios elementos contenidos dentro de un `<div>`:

```css
 
.container{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

.item{
  background: blue;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px
}

.item:nth-child(even){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> 1 </div> 
  <div class="item"> 2 </div> 
  <div class="item"> 3 </div> 
  <div class="item"> 4 </div> 
  <div class="item"> 5 </div> 
</div>
```

Puedes encontrar todo lo referente al trabajo con Flexbox [AQUI](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te ayude es en conjunción con el aporte de josanangel de ahí me base y me ayudo a centrar los input solo le agregue unas corecciones para que agarrara el espaciado de los input con el div form y en el div de arriba en vez de container le puse form-horizonatal y lsllso

[image]

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1>Registro</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form style="margin:0 auto">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Espero que te ayude es en conjunción con el aporte de josanangel de ahí me base y me ayudo a centrar los input solo le agregue unas corecciones para que agarrara el espaciado de los input con el div form y en el div de arriba en vez de container le puse form-horizonatal